# what is passed to the server on a meteor subscribe argument?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have seen code where people subscribe to collections in Meteor and the subscription passes and argument. E.g.

```
Meteor.subscribe('collection', arg);
```

and the related

```
Meteor.publish('collection', function(arg) {
   return Collection.find(arg);
});
```

the question is, where does that argument come from or what passes the argument to the subscribe method/function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically these will come from a session variable, for example:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  var groupId = Session.get('currentGroupId');
  Meteor.subscribe('invitationsForGroup', groupId);
});
```

Here we are subscribing to a collection representing the invitations for the current group. Note that the subscription is made inside of an [autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun) so it will automatically update whenever `currentGroupId` changes.

More details and another example can been seen [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe).